# How do I seperate a \n enclosed by quotation?

Tags: vb.net

I am processing a csv table. Example like this

```
1|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|"hello I typed \n
causing the table like this"|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|and continue like this|5|6|7|8
```

Initially, I use readline and split using "|" until I noticed when there's \n then the csv table will include 2 quotation mark.
I wanted to put the message into html so I need to replace the \n inside the quotation become this text " < b r > "

Second problem if the message itself has quotation mark it will be like this

```
1|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|"hello ""I"" typed quotation plus a \n
causing the table like this"|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|and continue like this|5|6|7|8
```

I truely can't think of how to handle it. Please help me

Comment: For example: `string1.Replace("\n", "</br>")`

Comment: Very smart people have developed very nice libraries to process CSV files because it is not as simple as it seems.  Look into CSVHelper for instance

Comment: you can't, I think you didn't understand it. If you replace the whole \n it becomes 1|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|81|2|3|4|"hello I typed \n
causing the table like this"|5|6|7|81|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|81|2|3|4|and continue like this|5|6|7|8

Comment: I think it's possibe but need to use regex, but I not know how to use regex

Comment: There is no "\n".  "\n" is a C escape sequence that represents a line feed character.  VB.NET doesn't use C escape sequences so there's no such thing as "\n" in VB.NET unless you're talking about straight text.  It's a line feed.

Comment: Use a [`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8) to read a CSV file in VB.NET.

Comment: it's implying the escape code, I know it's vbCr  but I just explain to him so he understands the situation. It be real dumb if I not even know to replace the word by myself

Comment: The character is a line feed.  That's what it's called.  It is represented different ways in different languages, although the C-style "\n" is the most common, but if you refer to it by its name then there should not be any confusion.  If you talk about "\n" in VB, where it has no special meaning, someone may think that you actually mean a backslash character and an "n" character.

Comment: so long ppl understand then it's alright. Did you get any clue to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here how to parse csv into html with \n involved. Thanks for jmcilhinney for the output table helped me understood how TextFieldParser handle next line.

```
 Using reader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(o.FileName)
                    reader.Delimiters = {"|"}
                    reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

                    Do Until reader.EndOfData
                        Dim all = reader.ReadFields()
                        w.Write(all(4).Replace(ControlChars.Lf, "<br>") 'message
                    Loop
 End Using
```

it's same as array it count from 0
so the result produced is

```
normal one look like this
hello "I" typed quotation plus a \n<br>causing the table like this
normal one look like this
and continue like this
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `TextFieldParser` is hardly rocket science.  Of course, it helps to read the documentation to learn how it works, which I'd wager that you didn't do.

I copied your data into a file and ran this code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Using reader As New TextFieldParser(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Test.csv"))
            reader.Delimiters = {"|"}
            reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

            Dim lineNumber = 1

            Do Until reader.EndOfData
                Dim fields = reader.ReadFields()

                For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To fields.GetUpperBound(0)
                    Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}): {2}", lineNumber, columnIndex + 1, fields(columnIndex))
                Next

                lineNumber += 1
            Loop
        End Using

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

This was the result, exactly as expected:

```
(1, 1): 1
(1, 2): 2
(1, 3): 3
(1, 4): 4
(1, 5): normal one look like this
(1, 6): 5
(1, 7): 6
(1, 8): 7
(1, 9): 8
(2, 1): 1
(2, 2): 2
(2, 3): 3
(2, 4): 4
(2, 5): hello I typed
causing the table like this
(2, 6): 5
(2, 7): 6
(2, 8): 7
(2, 9): 8
(3, 1): 1
(3, 2): 2
(3, 3): 3
(3, 4): 4
(3, 5): normal one look like this
(3, 6): 5
(3, 7): 6
(3, 8): 7
(3, 9): 8
(4, 1): 1
(4, 2): 2
(4, 3): 3
(4, 4): 4
(4, 5): and continue like this
(4, 6): 5
(4, 7): 6
(4, 8): 7
(4, 9): 8
```

Comment: I've seen it but not know how to implement it. Ahh thanks to your generated table I understood how to use it

Comment: Which is exactly why you should have read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) the moment you read the suggestion to use the `TextFieldParser` class. It includes an example and a link to the document for the `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` property, which includes this obviously relevant information: *"If the property is True, the parser assumes that fields are enclosed in quotation marks (" ") and may contain line endings"*. The information isn't going to get up and come to you. You have to go read it.

Comment: trust me I tried it I sure did, what I initially thought is it store all the values into a single array. Then it would defy the purpose to only get the message. When I saw your table then only I know it's counted using column. Thanks for your reply, I deeply appreciated it. The world just became better with helpful people like you. I like to upvote but I didn't get 15 rep yet

Answer (score 0):

Ok since I separate using readline by split ("|")

I thought of a solution

```
1. Introduce a boolean to check if the message part contains \n by checking the seperator |" to type this, use ("|"")
2. Set the boolean to true If Not line.Contains("""|") 
3. if boolean is true direct streamwrite.Write(line & "<br>") then check again if line.Contains("""|") else set boolean to false.
```

I think you got the idea so yea..

I managed to get the entire working solution, I hate to rely on other library as it's huge and inefficient if you just intend to use for small task like this onw

Comment: The `TextFieldParser` class is part of the .NET Framework so there's no additional library.  That's what you should be using, unless you actually need the additional functionality that third-party libraries can offer.  It is defined in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly, so some C# developers may be reticent to use it.  There's no reason for a VB developer not to though.

Comment: my solution work well. I have no idea if textfileparser is easy to use, I tried it just now but can't figure how to use since it separate out every value I can't like take out the message part, if I use split I can be like text()(4)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one (sorry not use regex):

```
    Using myReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\MyData\sts.csv")
        Do While myReader.EndOfStream = False
            Dim mstr As String = myReader.ReadLine
            Debug.Print(mstr)
            If mstr Like "#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*" Then
                MessageBox.Show("This Complete Line")
            ElseIf mstr Like "#*#*#*#*" Then
                MessageBox.Show("This First Line")
            ElseIf mstr Like "*#*#*#*" Then
                MessageBox.Show("This Last Line")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("This Continue Line")
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
```

Comment: sorry I don't undetstand what are you trying to do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator I fail to see if Like can help at all in this case

Comment: I just give sampel, i have express sorry, not used regex

Comment: But I think it can be changed to regex, and get line that separated by line feed, then next give <br> at the end of first line and continue line. But of course, itu just can be run for the sample format of 1|2|3|4|normal one look like this|5|6|7|8, so I use # for number and * for others

Comment: Sorry if it Will not give help at all